# Extend a plugin to include a widget option

Tags: plugins, widgets

I currently have a plugin (not a widget) that allows people to use shortcode to put the results on their web pages and posts.  Some people have asked for a widget option, so the output can go in the sidebar (if the theme supports it).

Is this possible?  I tried putting together a dummy widget (using code from the WP docs), but if I try to activate it like this:

```
 add_action( 'widgets_init', 'src_load_widgets' );
  function src_load_widgets() {

 register_widget('Foo_Widget');
 }
```

I just get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Foo_Widget' not found in /Users/me/My Webs/wordpress/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 324

Currently, the widget script is in the same folder as my plugin script since I want to same admin screen as I do for my plugin.  Not sure if this is the problem...so basically, I'm a bit lost.  Thanks for any help you can provide here.

Answer (score 1):

> A widget is a PHP object that echoes string data to STDOUT when its
>   widget() method is called.
>   -- [WordPress Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)

To create the widget you have to extend the WP_Widget class with your widget class.  You use the class name in the [register_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) function.

```
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {
   //Class methods here
}

function my_widgets_init() {
    register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: Thanks...actually, I figured out the problem and finally got it working..thanks for answering!

Comment: Please post your solution, Allen.